# Footnote marker normal size (using LuaLaTeX)

Tags: footnotes

I'm currently typesetting a book, using LuaLaTeX.

What I would like to achieve, regarding footnotes, is the following:

1. No footnote rule
2. Footnote symbols hanging in the margin
3. Footnote symbols should be full-sized in the notes (LaTeX handles the "text" part well)

I handle 1 and 2 using `footmisc`, and I also use `fnpct` to ensure good kerning w.r.t. the punctuation.

I just don't know how to handle 3.
Here is some kind of MWE

```
 \documentclass[mdemyvopaper, showtrims, twoside, openright,11pt]{memoir}
 %Bunch of stuff and packages
 \usepackage[marginal,norule]{footmisc}%note piè
 \usepackage{perpage}
 \usepackage{fnpct}
 \setfnsymbol{bringhurst}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
 \MakePerPage{footnote}
 %Bunch of other stuff
 \begin{document}
 Lorem\footnote{ipsum}.
 \end{document}
```

Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?  I'm not sure if I understand requirement 3) correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\footnoterule\relax

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \par \parindent=\z@ \noindent
  \llap{\@thefnmark.\quad}%
  #1%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}Text\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I think it's on the right way